# How to serialize PySpark GroupedData object?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a `groupBy()` on a dataset having several millions of records and want to save the resulting output (a PySpark `GroupedData` object) so that I can de-serialize it later and resume from that point (running aggregations on top of that as needed).

```
df.groupBy("geo_city")
<pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData at 0x10503c5d0>
```

I want to avoid converting the GroupedData object into DataFrames or RDDs in order to save it to text file or Parquet/Avro format (as the conversion operation is expensive). Is there some other efficient way to store the `GroupedData` object into some binary format for faster read/write? Possibly some equivalent of pickle in Spark?

Answer (score 3):

There is none because `GroupedData` is not really a thing. It doesn't perform any operations on data at all. It only describes how actual aggregation should proceed when you execute an action on the results of a subsequent `agg`.

You could probably serialize underlaying JVM object and restore it later but it is a waste of time. Since `groupBy` only describes what has to be done the cost of recreating `GroupedData` object from scratch should be negligible.